# Query Coherence using JMeter

Tags: java, web-services, jmeter, oracle-coherence

This is the situation I'm in:

I have a web service that is using the `Coherence` grid to store data for faster results. The grid holds specific `DTO` objects -- When new data comes in from the users, I update these `DTOs`. Now, I need to write specific JMeter tests for this. I can add a EndPoint (Restful WS) to collect these `DTOs` to verify that the objects are being updated, but that's kind of mixing the QA and Dev.

Is there a way to connect directly to the Grid using JMeter and query it for my objects? Or even any way to create a stand-alone java app and run it through Jmeter (add specific params for querys) to return the objects..

Thanks guys!
Ninn

EDIT: java class to collect coherence objects

```
    package disclosed.jmeter;

import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.AbstractJavaSamplerClient;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
import com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory;
import com.tangosol.net.NamedCache;

public class JmeterTest extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient{

    @Override
    public Arguments getDefaultParameters() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext arg0) {
        CacheFactory.getCluster().getMemberSet();
        NamedCache cache = CacheFactory.getCache("myCache");
        System.out.println("The value taken from the cache is: " + cache.get("message"));
        SampleResult result = new SampleResult();
        result.setResponseCode((String) cache.get("message"));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void setupTest(JavaSamplerContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void teardownTest(JavaSamplerContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can query any service from JMeter, either if you have Java library to access it, or by simulating raw TCP/UDP network traffic.

Best way is to have existing Java library to access service. Then you may use it from BeanShell Sampler, or write custom Sampler, it's easy.

Further details strongly depends on library you choose.

Comment: I'm working on creating a jar to access the grid now. I'm having a little trouble with Jmeter picking it up though. I've packaged the project's src file into a jar and put it into the jmeter/lib/ext directory, but it still doesn't show up as a class inside of the BeanShell Sampler.. any tips?

Comment: I got JMeter to pick up my class, but now I'm getting: --
An error occurred: Incompatible magic value 1885430635 in class file-- 

any time I try to launch JMeter. Any Ideas?

Comment: I edited my original post to to show the code that I used to get the coherence objects. I am still getting the above error. I named the file .class and the only other thing in the directory is the Manifest.MF file that is created when jarring.

Comment: I think the problem that I was having was with the src file, once I rebuilt the jar without the src file, it worked fine. I found another example that explains how to use the Java Request Sampler and Java classes to do things like this. I opened the test class in the Java Request Sampler, but it doesn't seem to be running anything. This is the other code: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379688/testing-java-classes-with-jmeter)