# JMeter. Synchronously share data between threads

Tags: testing, jmeter

How can I share data (in ideal associative array String -> Integer) between all threads within thread group? I'm interested in synchronous data access or at least atomic operations.

Or can I connect no-sql data storage (i.e. redis) and JMeter? Any existing solutions?

Comment: how about http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config where you can put this on top of your test and have key/value pairs from file being accessible from all thread groups.

Comment: And what about synchronization?

Comment: Sorry, just a weekend. I will explain my question tomorrow.

Comment: I don`t have enough time to write an normal answer for a nearly mounth. I`m too hardly working. Sorry (

Answer (score 3):

You should clarify what you intend to do with it and be sure you really need it.
If it's confirmed then you have different options:

- use third party library  http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/InterThreadCommunication
- code you own mechanism in java using Singleton pattern + Java sampler, see [Testing Java Classes with JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379688/testing-java-classes-with-jmeter)
- use jsr223 (groovy) + java custom code for this as before

But again ensure you need it as it can slow down jmeter or worse maje your test give wrong results or too optimistic ones if you add contention on JMeter through your custom classes.

Regards

Philippe M.